# fetch data from mysql database and show on the page - WORDPRESS

Tags: database, wordpress

I am new to WORDPRESS

I want to fetch data from mysql database and show on the page that are created in the admin panel.

Can any one please help me where to write the sql queries and how to access in the page.

Comment: why are you need queries in wp???

Comment: For example i created a table called schools and students. So I want to show that schools and students in the page

Comment: When debugging, sometimes you need to analyze the raw data.  While the question could have been written better, it's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you.

```
<?php $myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" ); ?>
```

Documentation  is [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class)

Comment: Thank you for answer, i am not able to under stand where to write this code and where the pages are located that i was created. can you please help me in this this is my first wp project

Comment: write the code in your template file. Details are here http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but for others who may come here.  You have some options.  Here is a list in order of control of access.

- If you have SSH access to the site server, you can login into SSH,
  and login into mysql directly, using the same credentials that are in
  the wp-config.php file.  Then you can run your queries directly.
- If the ISP has provided you a 'control panel' that include
  MyPHPAdmin, you can then use MyPHPAdmin to connect to the database
  and then run queries directly from there.
- You can also use a plugin like '[WP Data Access](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-data-access/)'.  I don't think
  it quite allows you to run directly SQL queries, but with it's data
  explorer, you can view the raw database entries.
- You could also make a custom, private page using a custom template.
  In the template's PHP code, could script up some SQL queries there, just like in the other answer here.